# Proof check that the set $A$ of subsequential limits of a series ${p_n}$ in a metric space is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $q$ be an accumulation point of $A$. There exists a point $x$ such that $d(x.q)< \frac{\delta}{2}- d(p_i,p_{m_j}) \tag{1}$ where $p_{m_{j}}$ is an arbitrary element of the subsequence {${p_{m_i}}$} which converges to $x$ (such a sequence exists since $x$ is in $A$) which means that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an integer $M$ such that whenever $m_i>M$, $d(p_{m_i},x)<\epsilon$. Setting $\epsilon=\frac{\delta}{2}+d(p_i,p_{m_j})$ we get $d(p_{m_i},x)< \frac{\delta}{2}+d(p_i,p_{m_j}) \tag{2}$ Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $$d(x,q)+d(p_{m_i},x)<\delta$$ using the triangle inequality, $$d(q,p_{m_i})<\delta$$ whenever $m_i>M$. So the subsequence ${p_{m_i}}$ converges to $q$ and it is in $A$. Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: In general topology, perhaps in mathematical analysis too, there is a difference between *accumulation points* and *limit points*.

Comment: does it matter here?

Comment: It's up to you. It does matter in some places around mathematical analysis, and certainly in general topology. Also, the set of accumulation points of any sequence of rational numbers, even if it has all rational numbers as its terms, is always **empty** ($\ =\ \emptyset).$

Comment: Here's the definition in baby Rudin, " A limit point of a set $B$ is a point such that any neighborhood of it contains a point in $B$ other than itself" this is identical with the definition of an accumulation point that I came across.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Now you may find out the definition of the accumulation point. Are the two definitions *identical*?

Comment: It is the exact same definition mentioned in Apostol's analysis. except, he restricts it to $R^n$.

Comment: Why would I do that? I am self studying here. There's no homework to do and no reason to trick myself into thinking that I understand something which I really don't. You judge too quickly.

Comment: Could you, please, quote Apostol, the whole definition? Apostol is one of the great writers but even a great writer may sometimes somewhat relax when they try to write down to Earth.

Comment: *Why would I do that?* -- your 2nd sentence of the *Question* is out of blue.

Comment: I added the picture. My thinking was that $\frac{\delta}{2}- d(p_i,p_{m_j})$ is a real number and $q$ (being an accumulation point) contains a point of $A$ in any neighborhood around it.

Comment: Km356, thank you! Too bad about the Apostol's text, especially that I have respect for his writing ability (is it the same Apostol who has written texts on Number Theory?). **XXXXX** Def: point $\ p\ $ is an accumulation point of $\ A\ $ iff $\ U\cap A\ $ is uncountable for every neighborhood $\ U\ $of $\ p\ $ (everything happens in a fixed topological space).

Comment: Ok. replace every "accumulation" by "limit". what's wrong with the second sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not correct. For instance, you don't say what is that $\delta$ that you introduce in the second sentence of the proof. And it makes no sense to mention $d(m_i,x)$, since $m_i$ is an integer, not an element of your space.

Comment: Check it now. $\delta$ is a real number.

Comment: I see no improvement. Your proof still doesn't say what $\delta$ is, not to mention why is it that $\frac\delta2-d(p_i,p_{m_j})>0$. And you still mention $d(m_i,x)$.

Comment: what should $\delta$ be? I removed the last $m_i$. $d(p_i,p_{m_j})$ is larger than zero and $\delta$ can be chosen positive. do you mean that we can't guarantee that $p_i$ and $p_{m_j}$ are not equal? then we can just choose $p_{m_j}$ not equal to $p_i$.

Comment: I cannot agree or disagree with your proof until you tell me what $\delta$ is and you still have $d(m_i,x)<\varepsilon$.

Comment: $\delta >0$ is a positive real number. I removed this $m_i$ and in case I forgot any, feel free to replace any of them with $p_{m_i}$ as this is becoming funny.

Answer (score 1):

> **Remark:** I see that Apostol's *accumulation point* is different from *limit point* due to his word *distinct*. Then, by a definition, a set is closed iff it contains all of its accumulation points (in the sense of Apostol).
>
> I understand that (perhaps) you want to prove that
>
> **Theorem**   The set $\ A\ $ of all accumulation points (in the sense of Apostol) of any subset $\ S\ $ of arbitrary metric space $\ X\ $ is closed in $\ X$.
>
> In particular, $\ S\ $ may be the set of all terms of a sequence in $\ X,\ $ for $\ S\ :=\ \{p_n: n\in\mathbb N\},\ $ where $\ p: \mathbb N\rightarrow X\ $ is an arbitrary sequence.

You may try to write a proof in a natural way by starting routinely (automatically) by expanding definitions:

Let $\ B\ $ be the set of all accumulation points of $\ A\ $. We want to show that
$\ B\subseteq A.\ $ Thus, let point $\ b\in B.\ $ Every open ball $\ U(b,\ r)\ (\mbox{where}\ r>0)\ $ contains a point $\ a\in A\setminus\{b\}.\ $ Then, in turn,
there exists $\ x\in U(a,\,\ d(a,\ b))\cap S\setminus\{a\}.\ $ Etc.

Be careful, you have to show that $\ x\ne b.$

*Good luck*.

Comment: **WARNING (about Apostol's definition):** Accumulation point $\ x\ $  of $\ S\ $ does not have to belong to $\ S.\ $ **#####** (The definition is fine, precise, but one needs to pay their attention to details without assuming anything as obvious or natural).

Comment: I encountered this argument before but couldn't justify the existence of a point $x$ a distance less than $r/2$ from some $a$ in $A$. I mean, what if no such point  exists..if $a$ is isolated in the sense that any other point of $A$ is at least a distance $r/2$ from $a$?

Comment: @Km356, that $\ r/2\ $ was a mth-typo (a routine wrong reflex). I've corrected it immediately but not fast enough for you :).

Comment: @Km356, the said point $\ x\ $ exists because $\ a\ $ is an accumulation point of $\ S.$ The intersection of the ball around $\ A\ $ is with $\ S\ $ and not with $\ A.$

Answer (score 0):

> I feel that there is a need for a clean presentation of the unhappy situation created by combining and discussing together the two notions:

- closed set
- accumulation point

> (*The hidden nuisance problem is due to logical element* "distinct". *This forces considering two cases where a single homogenous one would do*).

At the given elementary level, it is necessary to spell out the relevant definitions. Everything happens within a metric space $\ (X\ d).\ $ Our OP have already kindly provided the definition of the accumulation point of arbitrary set $\ S\subseteq X.\ $ Now, by definition:

**DEFINITION** $\ S\ $ is closed
$\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ A\subseteq S,\ $ where $\ A\ $ is the set of all accumulation points of $\ S.$

Now, under the above notation, when $\ A\ $ is the set of all accumulation points of $\ S,\ $ the OP problem can be sated as:

**THEOREM**   $\ A\ $ is closed.

**PROOF** Let $\ B\ $ be the set of all accumulation
points of $\ A.\ $ According to the above definition of a closed set, we have to show that

$$ B\subseteq A $$

If you read my previous answer all the way to "*Etc.*"
you will see that every point $\ b\in B\ $ is an accumulation point of $\ S\ $ hence $\ b\in A;\ $ in other words, $\ B\subseteq A.\ $ **End Of PROOF**

> *I felt it pedagogical to write these two notes instead of one, it should help -- that's how I feel*.